# проблемы с mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

На третьем запросе UPDATE пишет ошибку. Как решить эту проблему. Раньше работал с простым mysql и с такими трудностями не встречался.

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in (мой файл)

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','pass','db');

//первый запрос 
$q = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM `test1`');//запрос для примера

//второй запрос 
$q = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM `test2`');//запрос для примера

//третий запрос 
$q = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'UPDATE `test` SET `text'="simple text" WHERE id=1);//запрос для примера
```

---

```
if(isset($key)){
            $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM keys1 WHERE key1='$key'");

            $config = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM config WHERE name='download_version'");
            $config = $config->fetch_array();

            if($q->num_rows){
                $row = $q->fetch_array();


                ##VERSION
                if($config['value']!=$version){
                    $link = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM config WHERE name='download_link'");// тут ошибка Call to a member function query() on null
                    $r = $link->fetch_array();
                    die('[ERROR] Download new version. '.$r['value']);
                }

                ##FIRST ACTIVE
                if($row['activ']==0){
                    $date1 = date_create($date);
                    date_add($date1, date_interval_create_from_date_string($row['set_disable']));
                    $date_disable = date_format($date1, 'Y-m-d');

                    $mysqli->query(
                        "UPDATE keys1 SET
                        date_activ='$date',
                        time_activ='$time',
                        date_disable='$date_disable',
                        date_using='$date',
                        time_using='$time',
                        version='$version',
                        build='$build',
                        runningApp=runningApp+1,
                        cominform='$ComInform',
                        ip='$ip',
                        activ=1
                        WHERE `key1`='$key'");
                }
```

Comment: А если запросы делать так: `$mysqli->query("Ваш запрос")` ?

Comment: @Manitikyl, Не очень нравиться объекты, но попробую сейчас.

Comment: Валера, ну шо там?

Comment: `$mysqli` у вас `null`. А вы и не проверили. Соединения с базой то нету

Comment: @ArchDemon, оно есть первые запросы получают информацию.

Comment: @Manitikyl, вроде получилось. теперь другая ошибка. `$link = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM config WHERE name='download_link'");
     $r = $link->fetch_array;` Call to a member function query() on null in ........ Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in

Comment: почему `$mysql` если должно быть `$mysqli`?

Comment: @Manitikyl, это просто название переменной... я её могу обозвать $mysqli_ne_rabotaet ....

Comment: я понимаю, я думал опечатка, с переменными надо тоже быть аккуратней. тем более тут перепутать легко. у вас `$mysql` сбивается. так мы вам не поможет, примеры

Comment: @Manitikyl, смотрите выше КОД

Comment: Ну все правильно, `$mysqli` - сюда вы записали объект по работе с бд. Следовательно `$mysqli->query()`  так работать будет. А у вас `$mysql->query` одной буквы в конце не хватает, так дело не работает.

Comment: @Manitikyl, да работает. Но эта глупая ошибка возникла на стадии из Процедурного в Объектный стиль случилось. Почему тогда процедурный молчал?

Answer (score 0):

Выход из этой ситуации использовать Объектно-ориентированный стиль, по крайней мере мне помог именно он. Спасибо @Manitikyl, за советы.

---

`$mysqli_connect = new mysqli('localhost','root','pass','db'); $result = $mysqli_connect->query("SELECT * FROM test")->fetch_array(); echo $result['test_value'];`

Answer (score 0):

В третьем запросе ошибка синтаксиса обратите внимание на SET `text'=

```
$q = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'UPDATE `test` SET `text'="simple text" WHERE id=1);
```

Comment: Это пример. проблема решена.